# PermissionDenied: 403 error when I'm using Google Cloud Billing Budget API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google cloud functions and the `Cloud Billing Budget API` to get a list with all of my budgets, but I'm having the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable return callable_(*args, **kwargs) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__ return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking raise _InactiveRpcError(state) grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED details = "The caller does not have permission"`

`debug_error_string = "{"created":"@9627456.9324530376","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:54.128.19.5:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1069,"grpc_message":"The caller does not have permission","grpc_status":7}" > The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 449, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 268, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 265, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 22, in getting_data all_budgets = client.list_budgets(request = {'parent': BILLING_ACCOUNT}) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/billing/budgets_v1/services/budget_service/client.py", line 693, in list_budgets response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__ return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 290, in retry_wrapped_func on_error=on_error, File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 188, in retry_target return target() File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc) File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission`

What I've done is give the appropriate permissions (`billing.budget.list` ... `billing.budget.get` ... etc ) at the organization level to the service account of the function, but it does not work.

My code is this:

```
#main.py

import os
import get_budgets
from google.cloud.billing import budgets

def getting_data(data, context):
    BILLING_ACCOUNT = 'billingAccounts/XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX'
    client = budgets.BudgetServiceClient()
    
    all_budgets = client.list_budgets(request = {'parent': BILLING_ACCOUNT})
    budget_actions.budget_list(all_budgets)
```

```
#get_budgets.py

from google.cloud.billing import budgets
from googleapiclient import discovery

#BUDGET LIST
def budget_list(all_budgets):
    print('Budget summary')
    
    for budget in all_budgets:
        print(f'Name: {budget.display_name}')

        b_amount = budget.amount
        if 'specified_amount' in b_amount:
            print(f'Specified Amount: {b_amount.specified_amount.units} {b_amount.specified_amount.currency_code}')

        if 'last_period_amount' in b_amount:
            print('Dynamic spend (based on last period)')

        print('')
```

Is there something that I've forgotten?

Comment: Show the code that generated the error. Include the code that create the client to show how you are authorizing the client.

Comment: I just edited the question, and I added my source code.
Thanks :)

Comment: Is the service account a **member** of the billing account? Your question does not show how you are authorizing the client. You are using ADC, but how do you know which credentials are being used? Note: having the correct roles is not enough. The service account must also be a member with permission on the billing account.

Comment: I've created a custom role at the organization level that contains the necessary permissions. Then, I assigned the custom role to the service account of my function. And no, the service account isn't a member of the billing account. It may be the error? or is there something else?

Comment: Yes, the service account must be added to the billing account as a member. Reread my last comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to try that :)

Comment: You are right man! Finally, it works!! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was easier than I expected.

What I've done is add the service account as a member of the billing account.

Here is a quick video from Google of how to do it

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vti0OGQfLHQ

And in the comments of my question, you can find additional details.